# How to retrieve GSM signal quality parameters on Android?

Tags: java, android, parameters, gsm

I am trying to find out any methods to retrieve quality parameters like BER and CIR. The only thing I was able to find in Google and in Android Developer website was getGsmBitErrorRate(), but it seems to show -1 for all the time. So is there any way to get quality parameters in other way? Or may be I am just doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe a bug?: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
    TelephonyManager SignalManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener signalListener = new PhoneStateListener() {

        public void onCallForwardingIndicatorChanged(boolean cfi) {
        }

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        }

        public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
        }

        public void onDataActivity(int direction) {
        }

        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
        }

        public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state, int networkType) {
        }

        public void onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(boolean mwi) {
        }

        public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
        }

        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

            Log.e("onSignalStrengthsChanged: ", "GSM Cinr = "
                    + signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength()); 
        }

    }; 

    SignalManager.listen(signalListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH);
```